# Check elastic search deployment is currently available or not using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

i have created a Java service for elastic search CRUD operation i have given my business logic below there i am doing all my server side validation in that i have to check the elastic search deployment is currently available or not using my RestHighLevelClient of elastic search before inserting data into my index. i have given my code below.

```
public String createProfileDocument(EmployeeInformation document, String IndexName) throws Exception {
        String Id = document.getId();
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Id)) {
            return "ID is null or empty";
        }
        else if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(IndexName)) {
            return "Index name is null or empty";
        }
        else if(isTextContainUpperCase(IndexName)){
            return "Index name should be in lowercase";
        }
        else if(logic to check the deployment)
        {
            return "Elasticsearch deployment is not reachable";
        }

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(IndexName);
        indexRequest.id(document.getId());
        indexRequest.source(convertProfileDocumentToMap(document), XContentType.JSON);

        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return indexResponse.getResult().name();

    }
```

Could some one help me to achieve this in above code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked only about checking the status i willl suppose that you have access to the `RestHighLevelClient` instance

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;

...

public boolean checkTempConnection(RestHighLevelClient client) {
    try {
        return client.ping(RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Can't get status : {}", e.getMessage());
        return false; // Not available
    }
}
```

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a rest client and consider using the [sniffer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/sniffer.html) in order to implement connection failover
2. Check if [cluster is ready](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-cluster-health.html)
3. Check if [index exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-indices-exists.html)
4. Init index if not (using the [index api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-create-index.html))

Comment: The links in this answer are dead.

Comment: thanks @Adam893; they changed because the rest client (low & high level) is deprecated now in favor of the new Java API Client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/index.html, nevertheless, the links are up to date now